# Characterization of Discrete Sets in R

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let A be a subset of $\Re$ .
 Does anyone have a characterization of discrete sets A ( which only have isolated points ) ? I'm coming up with A is discrete iff ( A is finite) or (A is infinite and unbounded and ... ).

The problem is the "..." property.I don't know how to effectively express it ( actually i don't know if we can effectively and compactly express that property ) .

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion is false. Consider the discrete metric ($1$ for distinct points), on any infinite set. Then any subset is bounded, but every set is discrete.

The best way would be to simply state that every point is isolated. Either by stating that each point in the set has an open neighborhood which does not contain any other point from the set; or by using the metric and $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ argument which state the same thing.

---

Even in the real numbers you can find bounded and discrete sets which are infinite. Of course they won't be closed. Take any convergent sequence, without its limit, e.g. $\{\frac1n\mid n\in\Bbb N^+\}$. Then this is a discrete set which is bounded.

Comment: I guess i need to restrict my idea to R ( R is what i had originally in mind but somehow i naively wrote for a general metric space ) .

Comment: Pick any convergent sequence *without its limit point*, then the set of points left is discrete. But since the sequence is convergent it is certainly bounded.

Comment: The only clear thing we *can* say, is that such sets are at most countable. They can be finite, or infinite; bounded or unbounded; closed or non-closed. But if it is closed and bounded, then it is finite.